# Python. Pandas. Multiindex. Как перевести часть столбцов в строки-индексы?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

С помощью `df1 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\2022.csv', header=[0,1])` загружаю исходные данные.

[image: Исходные данные]

Подскажите как можно получить данные как во второй таблице?

[image: Требуемый формат]

Comment: пример исходных данные должен быть в вопросе в воспроизводимом виде

Answer (score 1):

В общем, в виду отсутствия воспроизводимого примера и неразберихи у автора вопроса с датами в желаемом результате, могу предложить следующее:

1. Во-первых, при чтении из csv у вас теряется мультииндекс, поэтому работа с двойным заголовком вам не нужна.
2. Как разберетесь с мультииндексом, можете использовать такой алгоритм:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'3.csv', header=1)

res = pd.pivot_table(df, values=["Sum1", "Sum2", "Sum3"],
                     index=["Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4"]).stack().reset_index()
```

res:

```
   Col1 Col2 Col3  Col4 level_4    0
0     0  bla  bla     1    Sum1  100
1     0  bla  bla     1    Sum2  200
2     0  bla  bla     1    Sum3  300
3     1  bla  bla     2    Sum1   20
4     1  bla  bla     2    Sum2   50
5     1  bla  bla     2    Sum3   30
6     2  bla  bla     3    Sum1   10
7     2  bla  bla     3    Sum2   80
8     2  bla  bla     3    Sum3   30
```